# Using simple enumerators in D

Tags: enums, d

Say I have the following enum:

```
struct Test {
    string value;
}

Test new_test(string value) {
    Test t;
    t.value = value;
    return t;
}

enum Foo : Test {
    A = new_test("a"),
    B = new_test("b"),
    c = new_test("c"),
}
```

I'm confused as to a few things. How do I pass this around to functions?

```
void do_something(Foo f) {

}
do_something(Foo.A);

// or

void do_something(Test t) {

}
do_something(Foo.A);
```

And finally, is there any way I can get the numerical value of the enum
for example

```
A -> 0
B -> 1
C -> 2
```

Something simple like:

```
Foo.A.id ???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write

```
 enum Foo {
     A = new_test("a"),
     B = new_test("b"),
     C = new_test("c"),
 }
```

You're basically creating a named set of values. They have no numerical value, the way you think - they're just regular structs. If you need to know the index of a value in the set (such that `getIndex(Foo.C)` would return 2), you could use this code:

```
// Gets the index of an enum value in the enum it's part of.
int getIndex(T)(T value) if (is(T == enum)) {
    // Iterate over all the members of the enum, and return the index if it's a match.
    static foreach (i, member; __traits(allMembers, T)) {
        if (value == __traits(getMember, T, member))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

As for passing it around, either way works, as you may have noticed. Again, there's nothing magical about enums. They're not a number disguised as a `Test`, and can be used like a `Test` in every way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why are you defining `Foo` as a `Test` here, you can just have an anonymous enum like:

```
enum Foo {
  a,
  b,
  c, 
}
```

or define it as a string:

```
enum Foo {
  A="a",
  B="b",
  C="c", 
}
```

in any case, it depends on your function design, if the function should receive only `Foo` then you should on pass a `Foo` and the same with `Test`, if the function you are writing should work with all `Test` objects not only these 3 predefined `Test`s then passing a `Test` will be your choice, however, if you want the function to work only with the enum you defined then use `Foo`, you get the point.

Regarding the id let's say you can have `Test` to contain another field called `id` and you initialize that with a number, now you can use that field as an identifier:

```
struct Test {
    string value;
    int id;
}

Test new_test(string value, int id) {
    Test t;
    t.value = value;
    t.id = id;
    return t;
}

enum Foo : Test {
    A = new_test("a", 1),
    B = new_test("b", 2),
    c = new_test("c", 3),
}
```

now if you want to get the index of one `Foo` you can use traits:

```
auto i = [__traits(allMembers, Foo)].countUntil(Foo.B.to!string);
```